# Django - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'admin'

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm in trouble.

**Python version:** 3.4.4

**Django version:** 1.10

**DB type/version:** SqlLite3

**Installed apps:** accounting, registry, ...

**Models (accounting):** Bank, Fee, ...

**Models (registry):** Company, ...

**Generic relations:** Company-Bank, Fee-Company, ...

**Admin site inline (accounting):**

```
class FeeAdmin(Admin):
    list_display = ['date', 'content_object']
    inlines = [registry.admin.CompanyInline]
...
```

**Admin site inline (registry):**

```
class CompanyAdmin(Admin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'contact_telephone', 'contact_cellphone', 'contact_email']
    list_filter = Admin.list_filter + ['residence_city']
    search_fields = ['company_name']
    inlines = [accounting.admin.BankInline]
...
```

**Problem:** the second installed app gives me the error in the title, if I switch the order in *settings.py*, the error is raised by the other app. The first one always run smoothly:

```
inlines = [registry.admin.CompanyInline]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'admin'
```

if registry is installed after accounting, or

```
inlines = [accounting.admin.BankInline]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'admin'
```

if the order is switched.

**Headers:**

accounting.admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes import admin as ctadmin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
import registry
from .models import Bank
from .models import Fee
...
```

registry.admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes import admin as ctadmin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
import accounting
from .models import Company
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about Python imports.

When you import a package, you don't automatically get access to all the modules underneath it; you need to import those specifically. So instead of doing `import accounting` and then trying to access `accounting.admin`, you need to explicitly do `from accounting import admin` and then accessing `admin.BankInline` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with `from registry.admin import CompanyInline`, but the only one working is `from registry import admin as registry`